# MYSQL Error 1060 - Duplicate Column

Tags: mysql, database

How can i avoid getting error 1060?

```
CREATE VIEW `new-query` AS

SELECT L1.Inv_Num, L1.Line_Num, P1.Prod_SKU, P1.Prod_Descript,
L2.Line_Num, P2.Prod_SKU, P2.Prod_Descript, P1.Brand_ID

FROM LGLINE L1, LGLINE L2, LGPRODUCT P1, LGPRODUCT P2

WHERE P1.Prod_Category IN ('SEALER') AND P2.Prod_Category IN ('TOP COAT');
```

Comment: create aliases for `L2.Line_Num`, `P2.Prod_SKU`, `P2.Prod_Descript`

Answer (score 0):

You have the same column names specified twice, so you need to alias the column names to unique names.  I just added l1_, l2_ p1_ and p2_ to the columns that showed up more than once.

```
CREATE VIEW new-query AS
SELECT L1.Inv_Num, L1.Line_Num l1_line num, P1.Prod_SKU p1_prod_sku, P1.Prod_Descript p1_prod_descript, L2.Line_Num l2_line num, P2.Prod_SKU p2_prod_sku, P2.Prod_Descript p2_prod_descript, P1.Brand_ID
FROM LGLINE L1, LGLINE L2, LGPRODUCT P1, LGPRODUCT P2
WHERE P1.Prod_Category IN ('SEALER') AND P2.Prod_Category IN ('TOP COAT');
```